# Paperback from 1982 or 1983 with a secret service agent in prison trying to save the president from assassination

Tags: story-identification, books

I bought a paperback from the PX in Italy in 1982 or 1983. The cover had a man riding a futuristic motorcycle with a woman riding behind him.

The story was about preventing a presidential assassination. The hero was a secret service agent in a super-max security prison who had been accused of trying to kill the president. He met a woman in the prison who was a doctor and knew how to beat the electronic tracking so they could escape.

She performed minor surgery on his back and placed the tracker on a bunny, then talked him through performing the same surgery on her.

That's all I remember. When I left the army, I left a lot of my books in Italy and I have been trying to find that book for more than 20 years. I'd appreciate anyone helping me find the title and/or author.

If, on the other hand, you happened to "find" my book in Italy, you could just return it. No questions asked.